# Number of $3\times3$-matrices with integer coefficients satisfying $\operatorname{Tr}(A^{\top}A)=6$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, permutations, sums-of-squares

We are asked to find the number of $3$x$3$ matrices $A$ **with all integer entries** satisfying $\operatorname{Tr}(A^{\top}A)=6$.

**My approach**

Assuming $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{11}&a_{12}  & a_{13}\\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} &a_{23} \\ 
a_{31} &a_{32}  & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$ and hence $A^{\top}=\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{11}&a_{21}  & a_{31}\\ 
a_{12} & a_{22} &a_{32} \\ 
a_{13} &a_{23}  & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$

We have

$A^{\top}A=\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{11}^{2}+ a_{21}^{2}+ a_{31}^{2}&\lambda_{1} & \lambda_{2}\\ 
 \lambda_{3}&   a_{12}^{2}+ a_{22}^{2}+ a_{32}^{2}& \lambda_{4}\\ 
 \lambda_{5}&   \lambda_{6}&  a_{13}^{2}+ a_{23}^{2}+ a_{33}^{2}
\end{bmatrix}$

So the problem reduces to finding integers $a_{ij}$; $i,j=1,2,3$ such that

$\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}a_{ij}^{2}=6$ which can be thought of as $\sum_{i=1}^{9}t_{i}=6$ where each $t_{i}$ is an integer and perfect square.

Hence we must partition 6 into 9 portions each of which is a perfect square,

**Case 1;**
9 $t_{i}s$= 6($t_{i}s$ have value $1$)+3($t_{i}s$ have value $0$)

number of matrices here would be $n_{1}=\frac{9 !}{6!3!}2^{6}$, since each permutation of the string of 6 1’s and 3 0’s corresponds to a value of $t_{i}$ and hence  $a_{ij}^{2}$ and because for each value of $a_{ij}^{2}$=1, we can have $a_{ij}=\pm1$, hence the number of permutations is scaled up by $2^{6}$

**Case 2**

9 $t_{i}s$= 1($t_{i}$ has value $4$)+2($t_{i}s$ have value $1$)+6($t_{i}s$ have value $0$)

number of matrices here would be $n_{2}=\frac{9 !}{1!2!6!}2^{3}$, since each permutation of the string of 1 2’s and 2 1’s and 6 0’s corresponds to a value of $t_{i}$ and hence  $a_{ij}^{2}$ and because for each value of $a_{ij}^{2}$=1, we can have $a_{ij}=\pm1$ and similarly for $a_{ij}^{2}$=4, hence the number of permutations is scaled up by $2^{3}$

No further partitions into perfect squares are possible

Thus the total number of matrices should be $N=n_{1}+n_{2}=\frac{7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot64}{6}+7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot4=7392$

Is the above reasoning correct for the number of such matrices ?

Please help me if anything is missing in above since I don’t have the answer for this in the exercise.

Comment: That looks correct to me.

Comment: The number of such matrices is infinite...over the reals or the complex. Are the entries of your matrix restricted somehow?

Comment: @DonAntonio I missed to write an important information on the constraints on each element of the matrix, each element is an integer. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is entirely correct. The presentation can be made a bit clearer as follows:

Once you have reduced the problem to solving $\sum_{i=1}^9t_i^2=6$ over the integers, you can immediately note that $|t_i|\in\{0,1,2\}$ for all $i$. Let $n_k$ denote the number of indices $i$ with $|t_i|=k$. Then
$$n_0+n_1+n_2=9\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n_0\cdot0^2+n_1\cdot1^2+n_2\cdot2^2=6.$$
From here it is clear that $n_2\leq1$. For $n_2=1$ you get $n_1=2$ and $n_0=6$, indeed yielding
$$2^3\cdot\frac{9!}{1!2!6!}=2016,$$
such matrices. For $n_2=0$ you get $n_1=6$ and $n_0=3$, yielding
$$2^6\cdot\frac{9!}{0!6!3!}=5376,$$
such matrices for a total of $7392$ matrices.